# Drag and drop a file on Windows Universal App

Tags: c++, directx, uwp

How to Drag and drop a file on Windows Universal App?

The only tutorial I've found, is this one:
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlDragAndDrop

However it operates on XAML UI objects, while I have a DirectX game and don't use XAML at all.

All I want is to drag and drop a file onto the Application Window (not a single UI element but the entire window), and in an event callback get the file full path.

I'm using C++, this needs to be for Windows 10 Universal App.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please let me know why you don't want to use XAML for such kind of scenario? Since the UWP XAML UI controls have very convenient support for drag-drop feature, and it also supports interop with DX via C++. [This online tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt227651.aspx) could be helpful. From this online help, you can find out that you could customize your own control to not show UI at all.

And if you want to implement dragging and dropping files without the help of XAML, it would require tremendous work: Dragging file to your UWP game means to share data among apps, so your implementation needs to follow [UWP data sharing pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt280384.aspx), which means you need to re-code everything XAML UIElement has already encapsulated, e.g.: implementing DropTarget Control Pattern.

For you case, if you only want to open file, then File Picker is more simple and convenient. If you still want to support drag and drop, it is high recommended to interop XAML and DX. Here you can find useful [guideline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh825871.aspx). You can build the app in C++, which would meet your concern about conserving memory and improving performance.

Please let me know if you have any question.

Comment: Sorry but I don't want to use a File Picker, or XAML.
What I want is to drag and drop a file, then be able to get its full path and file name as stored on the disk, and access it using standard C++ IO file access functions, such as fopen, fread, etc.
From what I see, UWP apps are too limited to do such simple things.

Comment: I don't want to use XAML, because: it looks complicated, it looks like it can reduce performance, I'm making 3D heavy DirectX based applications that need full performance. I handle rendering the entire interface with my own commands using DirectX rendering.
In WinAPI I can do this so easy, just handle the "case WM_DROPFILES" callback and get the file name. This works briliantly with just few lines of code.
Which means there's no real simple API for UWP to do this, and what I want is a simple API.

Comment: I don't want a FilePicker solution, because the more natural way (faster) is just drag and drop, if I already see the file I want to process, for example on the desktop, then I can just drag and drop, onto the app, so easy.
But if I have to use a FilePicker, then I need to:
1) click "open" to open the file picker
2) go to the path folder location of the file - very slow task
3) select the file
4) press OK.
So many things to do compared to just drag and drop.
Also I've followed your links, and it really sounds awfully complicated, honestly I don't know where to start.
Thank you

Comment: Imagine I'm writing an application that can convert files. For example, I drag and drop a BMP image, my app compresses it and saves as PNG image automatically in the same folder with the same name.
For example: I drag and drop "C:\Folder\image.bmp" file onto my app window, and my app will generate "C:\Folder\image.png"
So what I need, is a simple API, like:
void OnFilesDropped(String file_names[], int window_client_pos_x, int window_client_pos_y) {..}
where 'file_names' is an array of full path names of all files/folders drag and dropped onto the app

Comment: and other 2 parameters are the XY coordinates of the client window position where the drag and drop occured.
So in my example application I would do something like this:
for each file_names
{
  Image image; image.loadBMP(file_names[i]); image.savePNG(file_names[i]+".png");
}